# FeatureServer layer losing connection to Feature Class layers (ArcMap/ArcServer) on adding .lyr

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, layers

This is a question about using feature services as layers in ArcMap.

We have a issue where layer (.lyr) files (source from feature services) are not displaying individual feature classes when added to new ArcMap documents.

the set up is as follows:

- SQL Server 2008 with both SDE (& non-SDE) database(s).
- ArcGIS Server 10.2 (Serving data as Map Service & Feature Service) & security to  Map services is handled by (windows) network authentication. 
  ArcMap 10.2.2 to display the layers.

We have many feature classes within the feature service (as they cover the same theme).  If we add the Feature Service (From GISServer - ArcServer) to ArcMap document it loads as a group layer (as there are many feature classes) & if the feature service is used to create a .lyr again it load fine to ArcMap (as a group layer).

However if we want to use the individual feature classes, so save out layers (now called Feature Service Feature Classes) of each feature class there is a red explanation mark (I.e. missing data source) once loaded to a new map document.  This does not happen if you use a .lyr of 2 or more of the feature classes (so displayed as a group layer)

Has anyone else seen anything like this, is it a know issue?  We might be using an incorrect method to share these feature classes internally or there is a security side we have not considered.